# Qml HUD integration without MainView?

Tags: qt, c++, qml, hud

I'm working on an app with Qt Quick Components, I don't want to use any Ubuntu specific components because I want the desktop version of my app to be more portable than that (Qt 5.2 is enough of a dependency).

So my question is this, is there a good way to add HUD functionality with qml without using MainView? I wouldn't rule out using C++ either (my app is already mixing qml and C++).